# adb over wifi / bluetooth without using usb ever

Tags: android, adb, data-transfer

Android: 10
Mobile: Techno Spark 6 Go

My mobile's usb port have some problem, I can't connect my mobile to computer  using usb cable anymore, Now I need to connect mobile to computer to use `adb`, Is there any way to connect them over wifi/bluetooth?

Note: The main reason to use adb is data transfer, `adb pull /file/path/in/mobile` is way faster than `dukto app` or `airmore app`.

Comment: AFAIK for enabling adb over Wifi you need an USB connection (or a rooted device). `I can't connect my mobile to computer using usb cable anymore` Why? Fixing the USB problem would be the most effective way to get adb access.

Comment: `Why? Fixing the USB problem would be the most effective way to get adb access.` because it need to repair my mobile which i don't need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I Connected them by ftp, make your mobile ftp server, start the ftp server on your mobile, and download the files using:

```
bash$: wget -r ftp://YOUR_FTP_SERVER_IP_ADRESS:PORT_NUMBER/PATH/TO/FILE --ftp-user=FTP_USER_NAME --ftp-password=FTP_PASSWORD
```